# I write a code in C language for a problem. why it is not showing any output?

Tags: c

I got a problem while solving this C problem. I am not getting any output. How can I fix it?

Problem:

Limits 1s, 512 MB

Read an integer variable and print it in which the digits are separated into groups of three by commas.

Input

The input will contain an integer A (0≤A<2000000000).

Output

Print the formatted number.

Sample

Input:

```
1171123
```

output:

```
1,171,123
```

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long int a[10],n;
    int i=0,j;
    scanf("%li",&n);
    while(n>0)
    {
        a[i]=n%1000;
        n=n/1000;
        i++;
    }
    for(j=i-1;j<=0;j--)
    {
        printf("%li",a[j]);
        if(j>0)
        {
            printf(",");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");


    return 0;
}
```

I use this code. but there is no output. why ??

Answer (score 0):

there was a problem in the second loop. the loop was in decreasing order so the relation should be j>=0

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long int a[10],n;
    int i=0,j;
    scanf("%li",&n);
    while(n>0)
    {
        a[i]=n%1000;
        n=n/1000;
        i++;
    }
    for(j=i-1;j>=0;j--)
    {
        printf("%li",a[j]);
        if(j>0)
        {
            printf(",");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: arnab, thanks for your help. but if i do according to u, then also there is no output.